# How to prove that a language `L` is not a regular language?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language

Given the following question:

> Prove that the following language is not a regular language:
>
> A language `L` in alphabet $\Sigma = \{a, b\}$ where every word $w$ have more $a$ than $b$.

How would you prove that it's not a regular language?

I need help and any hint is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the pumping lemma for regular languages.

Comment: Or the Myhill-Nerode equivalence theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem). I find this to be **much** more convenient than the pumping lemma in most cases.

Comment: The Myhill-Nerode theorem is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [pumping lemma for regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages); the linked article has an example of how to use it. If you try that approach with the word $w=b^pa^{p+1}$, where $p$ is the pumping length, you’ll get the desired contradiction very easily. I find this the easiest approach, but you can also use the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem). If you use it, you might ask yourself whether any of the strings $a^k$ for $k\in\Bbb N$ have distinguishing extensions.

Comment: It would be interesting to know the basis for the downvote of a correct answer; in my book that’s vandalism.